# What is the URL to the company registration page in shopware6?

Tags: plugins, registration, shopware

In shopware 5 we have a company registration page (https://www.shopwaredemo.co.uk/registerFC/index/sValidation/H)

What will be the URL to the company registration page in shopware6?

Answer (score 0):

"It's not implemented yet, there is no possibility to register for another customer group." - Replay from shopware forum.